# Appium - Encountered internal error running command: Error: zipAlignApk failed

Tags: appium

This are my capabilities
`{
  "platformName": "android",
  "platformVersion": 9,
  "deviceName": "note9",
  "automationName": "uiautomator2",
  "noReset": true,
  "app": "/Users/curatio/IdeaProjects/ui_tests/apk/Curatio-debug-3.8.0.apk",
  "appPackage": "me.curatio.curatio",
  "appActivity": "curatio.curatio"
}`

And I'm getting this error

Encountered internal error running command: Error: zipAlignApk failed. Original error: Command '/Users/curatio/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/29.0.0-rc1/zipalign -f 4 /Users/curatio/IdeaProjects/ui_tests/apk/Curatio-debug-3.8.0.apk /var/folders/s3/ff6krr157v7g45sl5ysfqrs40000gq/T/201934-64772-19dtlxv.cag5/appium.tmp' exited with code 1. Stdout: ''; Stderr: 'Unable to open '/Users/curatio/IdeaProjects/ui_tests/apk/Curatio-debug-3.8.0.apk' as zip archive

I couldn't find an answer. I'm running Appium Desktop.

Comment: Check think [comment](https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/issues/849#issuecomment-475699060) hope it will help you

Comment: Thanks, @SubanDhyako. I've found the issue. The problem is with the SDK version 29. I had to downgrade and built the APK again.